# weird beeping when using the screen (galaxy s3)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

Whenever I use the screen it makes a beeping noise (two tones)
So if I am swiping or texting it will continually make the noise. Then sometime it won’t make the noise, and then it starts back up again when I’m using the devise. 
Please help I still have 2 years left of contract
Turning off and on won’t help

Answer (score 0):

If you go to **Settings** >> **Sound** then make sure 'Touch Sounds' (it might be called something similar) is not ticked, that **should** solve the problem